# Get unique on base of part of string but should print whole string

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want get unique count on base of part of string but after count whole string should be display

Sample Logs:

```
Error [VALIDATION_ERROR_OFFER_ALREADY_EXISTS] Code [VAL-00019] Message 
Error [VALIDATION_ERROR_OFFER_NOT_EXISTS] Code [VAL-00023] Message [Offer 
Error [WEB_SERVICE_CLIENT_INITIALIZATION_FAILED] Code [WS-00001] Message [Error while initializing CBCM Web Service Client.]
```

Now on base of first part between [], i want to get count in who logs file, but first line out of all lines should be displayed complete

```
 zgrep -h 'Error' my.log|awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}'|sort| uniq -c
```

Above only print

```
3 VALIDATION_ERROR_OFFER_ALREADY_EXISTS
1 VALIDATION_ERROR_OFFER_NOT_EXISTS
5 WEB_SERVICE_CLIENT_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

but i am looking that after count it display one complete sample line like

```
3 Error [VALIDATION_ERROR_OFFER_ALREADY_EXISTS] Code [VAL-00019] Message
```

Comment: Could you perhaps provide enough sample input that we can generate the results you get using the code you're working on so far? The sample you've provided only includes a single line with `VALIDATION_ERROR_OFFER_ALREADY_EXISTS`.

Comment: So if you have 3 lines with `[VALIDATION_ERROR_OFFER_ALREADY_EXISTS]`, which one of them do you want to display with count? First or last

Comment: There's no `Exception` in your sample log, how can you extract it?

Comment: @Utsav i want to print first

Comment: can you post the longest possible error message within that log (in terms of string length)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This prints the first line found along with the count of what's inside the square brackets, using your existing method:

```
zcat your.log.gz | awk -F'[][]' '
  !($2 in c) {c[$2]=$0}
  {a[$2]++}
  END {for(i in c){printf "%4d %s\n",a[i],c[i]}}
'
```

The logic here is that the `c[]` array will store first appearances of content, the `a[]` array functions as a counter for errors. The `END` block steps through the array (either would do, as they share indices), printing counts and content. Note that output from this is NOT necessarily in the same order as input, but you haven't specified that as a requirement.

You could make it a single command line if you like. I spread it out for easier reading.